# How to convert dots to commas decimal notations using excel formula

Tags: regex, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Let's say the user enters `1.234.567,89` or `1,234,567.89` or `1 234 567,89` in any excel cell one by one and in all the above cases the user should get `1234567,89` in the output cell.

Comment: consider substitute() but you will need to control when it does its replacements.

Comment: if you are using Excel do not use Google Sheets tag

Answer (score 2):

**Excel**

Try `TEXT()` with a custom format:

```
=TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""),".","")," ",""),"[>=100]#\,#0;#")
```

[image]

**Google Spreadsheets**

Try using `REGEXREPLACE()`:

```
=TEXT(REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(A1,"@"),"[ ,.]",""),"[>=100]#\,#0;#")
```

[image]

Comment: I have used substitute like that, still trying to find a way to combine several bits of text to be replaced so only one substitute is needed... plus 1 anyway.

Comment: @SolarMike, thanks, well one way would be to strip out all non-numeric values, but it would only start to overcomplicate things. Curious if you can come up with something :)

Comment: That's great, it worked. And also if I want o/p as 1234567.89 in all above cases then what do i need to change?

Comment: It's not working if my input is say 123,456.000 as result in that case is 1234,56 instead of 123456 or 123456,000

Comment: @sukhchainroyal, and are you using Excel? I'll have a look later tonight when behind a pc. But I don't know about arbitrary putting two or three numbers behind the comma. There need to be some rule to go by

Comment: @JvdV, Yes I am using Excel. You are right about arbitrary putting two or three numbers behind the comma. But as excel allows decimal separator placement under number formats and that is why i was trying the same to make the formula generic. Or you can just share the info what change we need to do if we have 2 or 3 or any numbers behind comma. Also it would be great if you can take a look on that case where we want result as 1234567.89 (notice dot instead of comma)

Comment: @SukhchainGoyal, to get a dot instead of a comma use text format `"[>=100]#\.#0,#"`, and to get three numbers behind the comma use: `"[>=100]#\,##0,#"`

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A), 
 IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, "\s|\.", ), 
 REGEXREPLACE(""&A1:A, "\s|\.", ",")), ))
```

[image: 0]